# Action Chain in loop works only once(Selenium/Python)

Tags: python, selenium, loops, automation

I'm trying to implement a cookie clicker bot. Cookie clicker it's just a <del>stupid</del> simple game, where you can click on the cookie to earn more cookies. You can take a look at that masterpiece [here](https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/).
The bot should just open the page, and click on the cookie 4000 times, but it clicks only one time.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait    
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "bigCookie")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(cookie)

for i in range(4000):
    actions.perform()
```

I see these messages in the console. What is wrong with <del>me</del> my code?
[image: errors]

Comment: This question looks [surprisingly familiar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OISEEL5eBqg)... yes, even, exactly the same as my question. I asked ChatGPT and he didn't help either, so I turned to good old SO. This code works perfectly: 
`for i in range(5000): cookie.click()`
But it really does look like the documentation says what you're doing at Tim's instructions should work, but it's just not. To my unlearned eyes, @Prophet's suggestion looks like it would create an `ActionChain` that grows longer with each iteration. Anyway, I just refactored to skip the `ActionChain`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you trying to do here is to load the gun one time and then to press on trigger several times in a loop...
To do what you wish you should slightly change your code as following:

```py
actions = ActionChains(driver)

for i in range(4000):
    actions.click(cookie)
    actions.perform()
```

BTW I guess this code will still not work since after the first click on the  `cookie` element even if it will appear again it will be a NEW, ANOTHER element even if it could be located with the same locator.
So trying to click it again will cause `StaleElementReferenceException`.
To make this work you will have to locate the `cookie` element again each time, as following:

```py
actions = ActionChains(driver)

for i in range(4000):
    cookie = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "bigCookie")))
    actions.click(cookie)
    actions.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution to the coding challenge. Note that just as @Prophet suggested, what I ended up doing was putting my code inside of the for loop.

#### Initial Imports and Declarations

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def getCount(count):
    try:
        v = int(str(count).split(" ")[0])
        return v
    except:
        return 0

#strings
url = "https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/"
english = "langSelect-EN"
bigCookie = "bigCookie"
cookieCount = "cookies"
```

#### Load the Page & Click "English"

```
options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)

print("Looking for language button")
language = driver.find_element(By.ID, english)
language.click()
```

#### The Guts of the Code

```
for i in range(5000): 
    try:
        print("Cycle " + str(i))
        cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, bigCookie)
        counter = driver.find_element(By.ID, cookieCount)
        cookies = getCount(counter.text)
        items = [driver.find_element(By.ID, "productPrice" + str(i)) for i in range(2, -1, -1) ]
        
        # I tried this both ways, and it clicks significantly faster if I don't use "ActionChains"
        # actions = ActionChains(driver)
        # actions.move_to_element(cookie)
        # actions.click(cookie)
        # actions.perform()
        cookie.click()

        for item in items:
            price = getCount(item.text)
            if price > 0 and price <= cookies:
                actions = ActionChains(driver)
                actions.move_to_element(item)
                actions.click()
                actions.perform()
    except:
        print(f"Cycle {i} Failed :-(")
```

Hope this helps!