# Why ActionsChain.perform() dosn't work in loop?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm learning Selenium, and I've tried to make an automatic clicker for this game https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/ .

I've made a Action Chain to click on the big cookie on the left side and put this into the loop.
But it click only once.

I tried, this loop also on https://clickspeedtest.com/ page, with same reasoult.
I also tried to add `actions.pause(1)`, and `time.sleep(1)` inside the loop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time


PATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

bigCookie = driver.find_element_by_id("bigCookie")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(bigCookie)

for i in range(10):
    actions.perform()
```

Comment: the large cookie thing has to be located every time before you click it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Action Chain in loop works only once(Selenium/Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70279480/action-chain-in-loop-works-only-onceselenium-python)

Comment: Yes, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

When you call methods for actions on the `ActionChains` object, the actions are stored in a queue in the `ActionChains` object. When you call `perform()`, the events are fired in the order they are queued up.

I assume that after the first time you run `perform()`, the queue stays empty and you probably need to store new set of actions in the queue. So something like this:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
    
for i in range(10):
    actions.click(bigCookie)
    actions.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

ActionChains are used in a chain pattern. In other words, actions can be queued up one by one, then performed. When you call [*perform()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53812686/7429447), the events are fired in the order they are queued up.

You were almost there. However to perform the clicks in a loop, you need to create the *ActionChain* including both the events as follows:

```
driver.get('https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/')
for i in range(10):
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#bigCookie")).click().perform()
```